# Allow Unknown values

Tags: python, python-2.7, colander

I am using colander while de-serializing JSON response. There is a field that is configured to have numbers only, but sometimes the response has null or non-numeric value for this field and then my application throws invalid error. Is there a way I could handle it in my program to give a default value, say NA, to the field.
Here is an example to explain the situation:

This is a sample:

```
class SampleClass(colander.MappingSchema):
    name = colander.SchemaNode(colander.String())
    testMark  = colander.SchemaNode(colander.Float(), missing=None)


class Sample(colander.MappingSchema):
    type = colander.SchemaNode(colander.String())
    student = colander.SampleStudent()

I want the following JSON to be accepted and not throw error for testMark as null

{  
   "type":"test",
   "student":{  
      "name":"a name",
      "testMark":null
   }
}
```

My apologies if there is something wrong in code, this is my first time in python.
Hope I have made the scenario clear. I would want to give the testMark field a default value, say NA, whenever the test mark is not a number.

P.S. This is just a sample scenario, can't post the actual scenario here.

Comment: The first thing that pops to mind is that that's where the `missing=None` is for. Is passing `"testMark":None` accepted?

Comment: missing=None implies that when the field is missing from the deserialized response, its value is replaced by None. My problem is what to do when the field is present the response but it has an incorrect value

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own SchemaType that accepts any value but deserialises it to a float or null.

http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/colander/en/latest/extending.html

```
class MyFloat(colander.Float):

    def deserialize(self, node, cstruct):
        if isinstance(cstruct, float):
            return cstruct
        else:
            return null
```

I didn't test this, but I hope you get the idea.